# Issue on Android 13 : Android — Repeat notification daily on specific time

Tags: android, alarmmanager, alarm

BroadCast Receiver Encountered an issue specifically on SDK 33.

Hello,

I used the guide at [[AlarmManager](https://blog.protein.tech/android-repeat-notification-daily-on-specific-time-c2b0f7788f93)] to establish daily notifications at a particular time. However, I've encountered an issue on SDK 33. The Alarm doesn't seem to trigger the broadcast receiver I've configured. How can I resolve this problem? Your assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you can try this https://github.com/JigarRangani/LocalNotification this is working on all android versions

Comment: I think this is private repo. Can you make it public?

Comment: you can check now

Comment: I attempted to execute your code in the emulator(Pixel XL API 33), but unfortunately, it didn't function as expected for me.
 val calendar = Calendar.getInstance().apply {
            timeInMillis = System.currentTimeMillis()
            set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 18)
            set(Calendar.MINUTE, 26)
            set(Calendar.SECOND, 0)
        }
At 6:26PM no any notification.